# Android: Are there any problems involved using IMSI

Tags: android, unique, identification

I know that there are problems with getting the phone number or the device ID (both can be null, device ID can be changed when the device is rooted etc.) but is there any problem with using the IMSI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes-  the user can switch sim cards.  If you want to uniquely identify someone, use a shared secret (login/password, cookie, whatever) sent over an encrypted channel.

Oh also-  wifi only tablets won't have an IMSI, they don't have a radio.